# Unable to insert extracted objects in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert/update the list of objects extracted using SQLAlchemy ORM.

```
def truncate_mytable(self):
    with self.session.begin():
        current_records = self.session.query(MyTable).all()
        self.session.query(MyTable).delete()
        self.session.expunge_all()
    return current_records

def compensate_truncate_mytable(self, objects):
    with self.session.begin():
        self.session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```

But while the objects have been extracted correctly, they are not getting written to the DB.

Could it be because there are also some protected attributes inside the objects, such as `<sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x11471bf70>` and `<ClassManager of <class 'lib.kaizen_models.models.MyTable'> at 1146673b0>`? The objects' type in the list is `<lib.kaizen_models.models.MyTable object at 0x11471bd00>`.

(I'm writing compensation methods, following Saga pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the objects are in a [detached state](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states), and this means  `bulk_save_objects` will try to [update rather than insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects.params.objects) them*.

The state can be reset to transient by calling [orm.make_transient](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=make_transient#sqlalchemy.orm.make_transient) on each object, after which they can be saved by `bulk_save_objects`.

```py
def truncate_mytable(self):
    with self.session.begin():
        current_records = self.session.query(MyTable).all()
        self.session.query(MyTable).delete()
        self.session.expunge_all()

    for record in current records:
        orm.make_transient(record)
    return current_records
```

Alternatively, you could [merge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) the objects back into the session before calling `bulk_save_objects`, but this might reduce the performance benefits that you want to obtain from the bulk operation.

---

* By default `bulk_create_objects`' [update_changed_only](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects.params.update_changed_only) argument is `True`, and since there a no changes in the objects' attribute histories no updates are attempted.  Setting it to `False` will emit `UPDATE` statements, but result in a `StaleDataError` because the `UPDATE` matches no rows in the empty table.

Comment: I tried `add_all` -> this worked for my use-case.

Comment: Funnily enough `add_all` was what let me work out what was going wrong, because when I tried it complained about deleted objects, which made me think to inspect their states.